# What is the difference between returning a pointer to a calloced int and returning the address of a initialized int in a function?

Tags: c

I'm interested the difference between these two scenarios:

```
int *function() {
    int i = 5;

    return &i;
}
```

and

```
int *function() {
    int *i = calloc(1, sizeof(int));
    *i = 5;

    return i;
}
```

is there a difference? If so, can someone explain what is going on in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a difference.  In the first scenario, the integer i is being allocated on the stack, which means it will get reused when the function returns.  In the second scenario, the memory is being allocated on the heap and will not get overwritten outside of the function call.